# Security risks in case of activation of developer options

Tags: security, developer-options

Is there is any security risks if I enabled  developer options in android phone (by clicking 7 times on build number)? Are there any risks when this option is showed in menu but switched off by toggle button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Explanation:**

No, there is no (technical) security problem with developer settings enabled. The reason why they are usually disabled is that they aren't important for regular users and some of the options can be dangerous, if used incorrectly. Not dangerous as in security, but your phone could do weird things because you enabled some option.

**Additionally,**

Sometimes, clicking this automatically enables developer options. **Do not worry.** The steps are easy for disabling.

We assume that you have already clicked 7 times.

1. Click "developer options".
2. Slide the on-off switch at the top to off.
3. Now your phone is like it used to be.

> Note: step 2 might be slightly different depending on the OS of your phone.

Answer (score 3):

No, clicking 7x just shows the hidden menu.